# Why can't I copy an array list to another within my if statement in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, arraylist, copy

```
if(newPatf > oldPatf){
                pat = oldPat;
                System.out.println(pat);
                System.out.println("SWAP");
            }
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is copy an array list 'oldPat' to pat. But when I run my current code no changes are made. However, I know that the if statement works as when the case is true SWAP prints.

Both array lists are different and so there should definitely be a change. Where for example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> pat = [1, 2, 3]
ArrayList<Integer> oldPat = [2, 1, 3]
```

In the event the scenario is true pat still prints out as [1, 2, 3] which is wrong as it should now be [2, 1, 3].

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please create a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, you're not copying anything here. You're just assigning another list to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using `=` is an assignment and does not copy anything, if you want to copy, you need to create a new list, and give the old as a constructor argument.

`if(newPatf > oldPatf) {
     pat = new ArraysList<>(oldPat);
     // or if pat is an empty list
     pat.addAll(oldPat);
}`

Or you can use `addAll()` to add the old element to the new list (if it is empty).

It sounds to me like you are missing some fundamentals, about the language.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public void so() {
    int newPatf = 1;
    int oldPatf = 0;

    ArrayList<Integer> pat = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    pat.add(1);
    pat.add(2);
    pat.add(3);

    ArrayList<Integer> oldPat = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    oldPat.add(2);
    oldPat.add(1);
    oldPat.add(3);

    if(newPatf > oldPatf){
        pat = oldPat;
        System.out.println(pat);
        System.out.println("SWAP");
    }
}
```

console:

```
[2, 1, 3]
SWAP
```

Comment: I figured it might be a mistake earlier on in my code, the example I have posted is just a snippet (modified example). Not sure if I can post the full thing on here :/

Comment: I have used your piece and it works - so thanks for that ... just trying to apply it

Comment: Just be aware that this has nothing to do with copying the elements in the list, you are changing the object that `pat` is referring (a pointer swap).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of pat to null then initialized it to be equals oldPat

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> pat = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        pat.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
        pat.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
        pat.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
        ArrayList<Integer> oldPat = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        oldPat.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
        oldPat.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
        oldPat.add(Integer.valueOf(3));

        System.out.println(pat);
        System.out.println(oldPat);

        pat=null;
        pat=oldPat;
        System.out.println(pat);


    }
```